# Data cleaning in pandas: replacing null values with specific strings if these strings are contained in another column

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I am currently working on a car emissions data set where I want to clean/standardise car model names. The data set is quite large, but here are the first 10 rows:

```
cars_em_df = pd.DataFrame({'manufacturer_name_mapped': ['FIAT', 'FIAT','FIAT','FIAT','FIAT','BMW AG','BMW AG','BMW AG','BMW AG','BMW AG'],
'commercial_name':['124 gt multiair auto', '500l wagon pop star t-jet', 
'doblo combi 1.4 95', 'panda  0.9t sge 85 natural power', 'punto 1.4  77 lpg', 'x4 xdrive20d se auto', '216d active tourer b37 f45','220d gran tourer b47 f46','x1 xdrive18d sport','320i xdrive m sport gt auto'],
'fuel_type_mapped':['Petrol', 'Petrol', 'Petrol', 'NG-Biomethane', 'LPG','Diesel','Diesel','Diesel','Diesel','Petrol'],
'file_year':[2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018,2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018], 'emissions': [153,158,165,86,114,131,166,200,151,149], 'commercial_name_cleaned':['124','500',None,'panda','punto','x4',None,None,'x1',None]})
```

The right-hand column **'commercial_name_cleaned'** is the result of my first cleansing exercise in which I have matched the names in column **'commercial_name'** to a list of standardised names from a different source. As you can see, these are quite simple and short names. Whenever I couldn't match a model name, my function returned 'None'.

As a second step, I would now like to do the following: If it's 'None', search for a specific string inside the adjacent **'commercial_name'** column and replace it with the model name I specified. I tried this:

```
    def str_ops(commercial_name_cleaned,commercial_name):
          if commercial_name_cleaned == None:
             if '216' in commercial_name:
                return '2-series'
             elif '220' in commercial_name:
                return '2-series'
             elif '320' in commercial_name:
                return '3-series'
```

Then I would apply this function to the dataframe:

```
cars_em_df['commercial_name_cleaned'] = cars_em_df.apply(lambda x: str_ops(str(x.commercial_name_cleaned), str(x.commercial_name)), axis=1)
```

It's important to note that if '320' or '220' etc. are not found in **'commercial_name'**, the function should not change anything and just return the value that was already in **'commercial_name_cleaned'**. However, when I apply the function, the entire **'commercial_name_cleaned'** column just becomes 'None' values. So there must be something wrong with the function. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: How many of these conditions are you looking to use and how complicated is their logic... for instance - is it always going to be simple substring testing or more complicated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `None` values in `commercial_name_cleaned` column because you are not returning anything from the function `str_ops`, **when you don't explicitly return anything implicitly `None` type is returned.**

Replace:

```
def str_ops(commercial_name_cleaned,commercial_name):
    if commercial_name_cleaned == None:
        if '216' in commercial_name:
            return '2-series'
        elif '220' in commercial_name:
            return '2-series'
        elif '320' in commercial_name:
            return '3-series'
```

**With:**

```
def str_ops(commercial_name_cleaned,commercial_name):
    if commercial_name_cleaned == 'None':
        if '216' in commercial_name:
            return '2-series'
        elif '220' in commercial_name:
            return '2-series'
        elif '320' in commercial_name:
            return '3-series'
    else:
        return commercial_name_cleaned
```

**Output:**

```
manufacturer_name_mapped                   commercial_name  ... emissions  commercial_name_cleaned
0                     FIAT              124 gt multiair auto  ...       153                      124
1                     FIAT         500l wagon pop star t-jet  ...       158                      500
2                     FIAT                doblo combi 1.4 95  ...       165                     None
3                     FIAT  panda  0.9t sge 85 natural power  ...        86                    panda
4                     FIAT                 punto 1.4  77 lpg  ...       114                    punto
5                   BMW AG              x4 xdrive20d se auto  ...       131                       x4
6                   BMW AG        216d active tourer b37 f45  ...       166                 2-series
7                   BMW AG          220d gran tourer b47 f46  ...       200                 2-series
8                   BMW AG                x1 xdrive18d sport  ...       151                       x1
9                   BMW AG       320i xdrive m sport gt auto  ...       149                 3-series
```